# Não há resultados no inner join

Tags: mysql

boa tarde, gente.
estou resolvendo uns exercícios aqui, e essa query, que deveria estar trazendo algumas linhas, está vindo vazia.

Preciso selecionar os alunos que estão matriculados em MAT e POR

```
SELECT NOME_ALUNO, ID_DISCIPLINA FROM TB_ALUNO A
    INNER JOIN TB_ALUNO_DISCIPLINA AD
    ON A.COD_ALUNO = AD.COD_ALUNO
    WHERE AD.ID_DISCIPLINA = 'MAT' AND AD.ID_DISCIPLINA = 'POR'
    GROUP BY A.COD_ALUNO, AD.ID_DISCIPLINA;
```

Podem me ajudar?

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Answer (score -2):

Pelo que eu entendi você quer que retorne os alunos onde a disciplina seja MAT ou POR, então eu acredito que o erro está nesta linha:

```
WHERE AD.ID_DISCIPLINA = 'MAT' AND AD.ID_DISCIPLINA = 'POR'
```

Mude o AND para OR

Mude para:

```
WHERE AD.ID_DISCIPLINA = 'MAT' OR AD.ID_DISCIPLINA = 'POR'
```

Comment: Ou operador IN ..  WHERE AD.ID_DISCIPLINA IN ('MAT','POR')